# call activity inside PagerAdapter

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, android-pageradapter

Can I call activity inside PagerAdapter?

the click button is inside `public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)`

can I do that in xamarin and visulal studio 2013?

```
 public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        public SamplePagerAdapter() : base()
        {

            items.Add("               All Categories        ");
            items.Add("        Featured                          ");


        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj)
        {
            return view == obj;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {


            View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
                 container.AddView(view);


            if (position == 0)
            {
               view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
                container.AddView(view);
                var imgcarbtn = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgcar);
                imgcarbtn.Click += imgcarbtn_Click;
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                 view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.featuredadds, container, false);

            }

            int pos = position + 1;

          Console.Out.WriteLine(pos);
           container.AddView(view);

            return view;
        }

        void imgcarbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            activity.StartActivity(typeof(Labas));
           //weakactivity(Labas) ;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private WeakReference weakactivity;
        private Activity activity
        {
            get { return weakactivity.Target as Activity; }
            set { weakactivity = new WeakReference(value); }
        }

        public SamplePagerAdapter(Activity activity)
            : base()
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public string GetHeaderTitle (int position)
        {
            return items[position];
        }

        public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object obj)
        {
            container.RemoveView((View)obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

Pass the Activity reference in the constructor of the PagerAdapter. Make sure you store it as WeakReference though to prevent activity leak.

```
public class YourPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
{
  private WeakReference weakactivity;
  private Activity activity
  {
    get { return weakactivity.Target as Activity; }
    set { weakactivity = new WeakReference(value); }
  }

  public YourPagerAdapter(Activity activity) : base()
  {
    this.activity = activity;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice use of weak reference!

Comment: not working here  public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
        {

Comment: what should I put here to call the activity using the weakreference?  void imgcarbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               //weakactivity(NewActivity) ;
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with the Activity? You can now use activity.SomeMethod();

Comment: I am trying to call another activity. the click function is inside the pageadpater. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "call" another Activity? Start new activity on click event? If so, then use activity.StartActivity(typeof(SomeActivity));

Comment: I tried to use your code and the activity.StartActivity. But I got this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object  pointing at the return weakactivity.Target as Activity;

Comment: That means you are passing null to the constructor of your SimplePagerAdapter when you are instantiating the adapter.

Comment: ahh.. How can I fix that?

Comment: Show some more code where you call new SimplePagerAdapter(activity);

Comment: That is your implementation of the SimplePagerAdapter. What i meant was the code where you **use** this adapter. So something like Adapter adapter = new SimplePagerAdapter(this); viewpager.SetAdapter(adapter);